# JavaScript Action Button

Tags: javascript, button

I have this code. What it does is that when I click the Save button user gets registered. I want to automate this button. I want to auto click this button. So when the page loads. Users don't have to click the save button. User get register automatically. I have already hardcoded the user information.

```
var buttons = [];

buttons.push({

    text: lang.save,

    action: function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

When DOM (html page) is loaded, click the button.

```
// As soon as the page is loaded, auto save.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM loaded');

    const saveButton = document.getElementById("button-id");
    saveButton.click();
});
```